# Is there a limited number of features for QSVM in Qiskit-Aqua?

Tags: qiskit, programming

Why do all tutorials that use QSVM from qiskit Aqua library have the number of features equal to 2?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-community-tutorials/blob/f589e0aa4b31de30aed01f8219abdd3e56771653/machine_learning/qsvm_multiclass.ipynb) is a tutorial that uses three classes! If you want to use more than two classes, you need a `multiclass_extension` which is provided as a parameter to the QSVM

```
svm = QSVM(feature_map, training_input, test_input, total_array,
          multiclass_extension=AllPairs(_QSVM_Estimator, [feature_map]))
```

As shown in the tutorial. There are a few multiclass extensions to choose from, which are all [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/tree/master/qiskit/aqua/components/multiclass_extensions).